# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Exception in Exported JAR From Eclipse With Library depenndency

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have exported the Jar from Eclipse project which contains external Jar as a dependency. But when I tried to use that exported Jar, I got the exception **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** for the class which is present in the external jar.
So I think the external jars are not binds correctly when I export the project as a jar.

Do anyone have the resolution for the same?

Comment: When you use the exported JAR you have to specify the external JAR in the classpath/modulepath. Alternatively, you can create a single fat JAR which contains everything, including the external JARs.

Comment: I also try to append the external jar in classpath, but still it showing the same exception

Comment: Please, describe how you exported the JAR (there are several possibilities) and how you use the exported JAR (command line call). If you do _File > Export...: Java > Runnable JAR file_ you can choose _Package required libraries into generated JAR_.

Comment: For Export I used File>Export ..Java>Jar File. and I also ticked options Add Directory Entries and Export Java source File and Resource. To use Exported Jar I try to fetch the method which exists in that jar where I got this issue

Comment: Does exporting as _Runnable JAR file_ with _Package required libraries into generated JAR_ solve your problem?

Comment: I exported Runnable Jar File with option Extract required libraries into generated Jar. Now It's Working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To export your application as a fat JAR that also contains the required external JARs, do the following:

1. *File > Export...: Java > **Runnable JAR file***
2. In the export dialog choose ***Package required libraries into generated JAR***